# Why does page type selectors when using with ctr+ P do no work?

Tags: javascript, css, sass

I’m trying to toggle print layout option in landscape/portrait mode 
based on dom element. But it doesnt seem to work.
**Note** : I want this working only on chrome.

I have tried page type selectors:

```
@page vertical {
 size: A4 portrait;
 margin: 0.5in;
}

@page horizontal {
 size : A4 landscape;
 margin: 0.5in;
}

div {
  page : vertical;
}

span {
 page : horizontal
}
```

So for div selectors, whenever we print, the page should be displayed in portrait mode.

And for span selectors, the page should be displayed in landscape mode.

Comment: never heard of @page, do you have a link to some documentation where this is mentioned?

Comment: @cloned  

1. https://www.quackit.com/css/at-rules/css_page_at-rule.cfm
 2. https://www.cssportal.com/css-properties/page.php
3.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page

Comment: thanks, google was not very helpful for searching "page css" :-D According to the documentation `You can only change the margins, orphans, widows, and page breaks of the document. Attempts to change any other CSS properties will be ignored.`  But your first link says your CSS should be correct. Did you try the example with section and table? Maybe it isn't fully supported everywhere. :/

Comment: @cloned yes. doesnt seem to work

Comment: can you give the html.

I tried and  seem to only be able to set the orientation for the page and not sections of it. I was able to put page breaks, but it still wouldn't change the orientation of the next page. It's pretty weird.